# Word2vec continuous bag of words and skip grams model

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, word2vec, word-embeddings

Recently, I want to understand word2vec.
I know there are two algorithm behind word2vec.
One is CBOW another is Skip grams model.

Here is question, is CBOW also have windows size like skip-gram model and will do iteration of corpus?

For example, "I am eating pizza now", let say windows size is 2.

In CBOW, feature will be "I, am, pizza, now", label will be "eating".

Is it will also do "I" as label, "am, eating" as feature and so on in iteration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In CBOW you are predicting a target word from source context words.
In Skip-gram it is the inverse, given a target word, it predicts source context words.

CBOW also creates vector representations for all the words apart from just "eating" in your example by constructing tuples for training based on the window size.

So considering the window size of 2, the data would look like this:

([I, eating], am), ([am, pizza], eating), ([eating, now], pizza) and so on and so forth.

Comment: By the way, in this example, I wonder the windows size is 1 instead 2?
Saw from here: https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/word2vec

Comment: With window size 1, the input and output pairs get reduce to size of (1,1) . Also the best way to really understand this is to generate word embeddings of varied sizes and visualize them with either tensorboard or run a tsne and visualize via matplotlib. It will help in understanding word embeddings better.